# Recycler View Is So Slow when using if statement for ( i - 0 )

Tags: android, user-interface, chat, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a chat app. In chat activity, I wanted to show profile picture only on the first item and when I used Runnable (onItemChanged) it slowed down my recycler view very much and now it looks like I added motion blur to my recycler view and it is very very lazy.

Here is a gif of my chat activity:
https://i.gyazo.com/f0489ca7fe9ad28519061c0ff8963fb4.gif

Im not actually sure that it is Runnable that slows down my recycler view but when I remove :

```
if (i > 0)

            if (mMessageList.get(i - 0).getFrom().equals(mMessageList.get(i).getFrom())) {
                makeDPInvisible(i - 0);

            }

        if (invisibleIds.contains(i)) {
            viewHolder.displayName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.profileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
```

and

```
private void makeDPInvisible(final int i) {
        invisibleIds.add(i);
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyItemRangeChanged(i);
            }
        });

    }
```

my recycler is very smooth and without any problems...

Here is my MessaageAdapter.java

```
/**
 * Created by Aryojj on 24/07/17.
 */

public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ArrayList<Integer> invisibleIds = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Messages> mMessageList;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> mMessageList) {

        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;


    }

    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout ,parent, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        return new MessageViewHolder(v);

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }


    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView messageText;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;
        public TextView displayName;
        public ImageView messageImage;

        public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
            profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);
            displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_text_layout);
            messageImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_image_layout);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        String message_sender_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        Messages c = mMessageList.get(i);

        String from_user = c.getFrom();
        String message_type = c.getType();

        if (i > 0)

            if (mMessageList.get(i - 0).getFrom().equals(mMessageList.get(i).getFrom())) {
                makeDPInvisible(i - 0);

            }

        if (invisibleIds.contains(i)) {
            viewHolder.displayName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.profileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

            mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(from_user);

            mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                    viewHolder.displayName.setText(name);

                    Picasso.with(viewHolder.profileImage.getContext()).load(image)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(viewHolder.profileImage);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            if (message_type.equals("text")) {

                viewHolder.messageText.setText(c.getMessage());
                viewHolder.messageImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            } else {

                viewHolder.messageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(viewHolder.profileImage.getContext()).load(c.getMessage())
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(viewHolder.messageImage);

            }

        }

    private void makeDPInvisible(final int i) {
        invisibleIds.add(i);
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyItemRangeChanged(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: why  cant you use  if (mMessageList.get(i - 0).getFrom().equals(mMessageList.get(i).getFrom())) {
             viewHolder.displayName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.profileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

            } what is the need for makeDPInvisible()

Comment: get notifyItemRangeChanged(i); out of runnable block, then try

Comment: @lib4 then where i add the notifyItemChanged ? and invisibleIds.add(i)

Comment: where i put it?

Comment: @lib4 and what you said doesnt work